# How to define a property that can be string or null in OpenAPI (Swagger) without declaring it in schema?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, swagger-ui, openapi, flask-restful, swagger-editor

I am currently making a flask-sqlalchemy microservice and i am facing a problem with regards the acceptance of null value in OAS 3.0.0
for example

this is my request body

```
"Target": [
{"_id": 1, "score": null}
]
}
```

but when I tried to post it this is the error

```
{
  "detail": "{'Target': [{'_id': 1, 'score': None}]} is not valid under any of the given schemas",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "about:blank"
}
```

it does only accept null if I set on the schema for example

```
properties:
  _id:
    type: string
  score: 
    type: integer
    nullable: true
```

but when I used another data except score it doesn't allow null value

example

```
"Target": [
{"_id": 1, "newdata": null}
]
}
```

can we make it nullable even it does not declared in the schema?

Comment: *"but when I used another data except score it doesn't allow null value"* - did you maybe mean "it allows null value"?

Comment: no it does not, example here is 

```
properties:
  _id:
    type: string
  score: 
    type: integer
    nullable: true
```
"Target": [
{"_id": 1, "score": null}
]
}
all i can accept is that however when u change to 

"Target": [
{"_id": 1, "newdata": null}
]
}

it will response
{
  "detail": "{'Target': [{'_id': 1, 'newdata': None}]} is not valid under any of the given schemas",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "about:blank"
}